# JQuery autocomplete doesn't work when there is a line break

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, line-breaks

I am using Autocomplete with custom data [jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) and some items have multiple lines. Unfortunately at those line breaks there is an *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token* error. Playing with the database a little bit I found out that replacing the line break with **&#010** fixes the error.

Now the question is: how do I replace, in PHP, a line break to &#010?

For example, this is the data in the database that gives me the error:

```
- Audio Mixer
- 2 Powered Speaker
- Podium Mic
```

this is the data in the database that works well:

```
- Audio Mixer&#010;- 2 Speakers&#010;- Wired Podium Mic
```

I use PHP to get data into the mysqli table

Comment: Try using `replace("\r\n", "\n", $data)`

Comment: No luck. Still saving as in the first example above. Thanks!

Comment: You're awesome Psi! I did this: str_replace("\r\n", "&#010", $InvText)

Comment: Isn't there a semicolon missing then? `str_replace("\r\n", "&#010;", $InvText)`

Comment: Good eye! Even though I am fixing it, it works both ways :-o